# Object don't align

Tags: html, css

I have the code below but for some reason the instructions and fixed divs don't line up. I have tried so many different things but I just can't figure it out. Even if I assign the same class to both divs the alignment is still off. Both divs should have the same height and text and hr should line up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    
    h2 {
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    .margin2 {
      padding-left: 20px;
      background-color: #e8edf0;
      width: 1240px;
      margin: auto;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .instructions {
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      background-color:white;
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    .fixed {
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      background-color:white;
      width: 610px;
    }
    
    .flex-item {
      background-color:green;
      width: 630px;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .container2 {
      display:flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="margin2">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="fixed">
        <h2 class="h2">Text</h2>
        <hr style="width:100%;text-align:left;height:2px;margin-left:0;margin-bottom:20px;border:none;background-color:#004EA2">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="instructions">
          <h2 class="h2">Text</h2>
          <hr style="width:100%;text-align:left;height:2px;margin-left:0;margin-bottom:20px;border:none;background-color:#004EA2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto;` to `.instructions`.

```
.instructions {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
}


h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.margin2 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #e8edf0;
  width: 1240px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.instructions {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color:white;
  width: 300px;
overflow: auto;
}

.fixed {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color:white;
  width: 610px;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color:green;
  width: 630px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container2 {
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="margin2">
<div class="container2">
  <div class="fixed">
    <h2 class="h2">Text</h2>
    <hr style="width:100%;text-align:left;height:2px;margin-left:0;margin-bottom:20px;border:none;background-color:#004EA2">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="instructions">
      <h2 class="h2">Text</h2>
      <hr style="width:100%;text-align:left;height:2px;margin-left:0;margin-bottom:20px;border:none;background-color:#004EA2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Though I'm not sure why because looking at the overflow documentation, I don't think the problem was my element didn't fit?

Comment: @sjaak , while inspecting, we can see that the margin of H2 goes outside  the div. In such cases we can fix it by adding `overflow` or `float` to the containing div... Other values for overflow like `hidden` or `scroll` will also fix this.. `float:left;` also fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, I have made some changes: Hope it works for you.
If you remove the class "flex-item", you will get the exact same look/view.

```
<div class="margin2">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="fixed">
        <h2 class="h2">Text</h2>
        <hr style="width:100%;text-align:left;height:2px;margin-left:0;margin-bottom:20px;border:none;background-color:#004EA2">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item fixed">
        <!-- <div class="fixed"> -->
          <h2 class="h2">Text</h2>
          <hr style="width:100%;text-align:left;height:2px;margin-left:0;margin-bottom:20px;border:none;background-color:#004EA2">
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works in the sense that it fixes the alignment but it also changes the overall layout so I've accepted Felix's answer as it fixes the alignment without changing the layout.